How do you enable X11 verbose debugging in Ubuntu 24.04
I've got a problem where my screens freeze randomly. Everything is still running, but all new output to my displays is halted with the exception of 1 (The built in display for my laptop). I can move applications to/from the frozen screens but, obviously, I cannot see what is being displayed anymore as the screens no longer show new data. This seems related to X11 since enabling wayland seems to prevent the issue from ever happening. HOWEVER, even though I would love to keep wayland as a long term solution, there are multiple applications that I need to use which do not have wayland support yet (Microsoft Teams, OBS studio, ect.. ).
Where do I start on properly diagnosing this issue with X11? I'm assuming that I would need to enable some type of verbose debugging and then look at logs the exact second that the issue shows up to understand the issue. How do I enable Verbose X11 debug logging on Ubuntu 24.04?
